# How to remove unwanted text from a string?

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that returns the title from a website, the only issue is, it also contains lots of unwanted HTML (I think?). Most of the time, I can overcome this by removing the common characters using the following code.

```
on CharacterRemover(inputString, ReplaceChar)

set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ReplaceChar
set pieces to text items of inputString -- break string apart at commas
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "" -- or whatever replaces the comma
set inputString to pieces as text -- put string back together using whatever
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

return inputString

end CharacterRemover

set FirstTitle to "<!-- react-text: 45 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- 
react-text: 46 -->Megan Fox<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 47 -- 
>”<!-- /react-text -->" --the format of the returned title
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "-")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, ">")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "<")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "!")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "/")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "reacttext")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, ":")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "”")
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, "“")

set z to 0

repeat 10 times
set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, z)
set z to z + 1
end repeat

set FirstTitle to CharacterRemover(FirstTitle, " ")

display dialog FirstTitle
```

However, since this code removes the numbers, when I get titles such as

```
<!-- react-text: 477 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 478 -->iPhone 8<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 479 -->”<!-- /react-text -->
```

it returns as "iPhone" instead of "iPhone 8"

edit: on the website "higherorlower.com" I am using javascript "document.getElementsByClassName" to return the title of the given search amount

any ideas to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you look at (and, if you wish, feedback about) the method you're using to retrieve the information from the website, as the best and most reliable option would be to use a different method such that you don't have to deal with the `ReactJS` comments at all.

If you'd included that part of your AppleScript along with the rest, it might have been a chance to solve your problem at its source.

Nonetheless, here's one method of stripping the tags from your text strings, though by no means the only method, nor necessarily the most graceful or efficient.  But it's reasonably clean and, presuming the tags are all simple `ReactJS` comment tags, it will do a reliable job.

```
    set string1 to "<!-- react-text: 45 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- \nreact-text: 46 -->Megan Fox<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 47 -- \n>”<!-- /react-text -->"
    
    set string2 to "<!-- react-text: 477 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 478 -->iPhone 8<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 479 -->”<!-- /react-text -->"
    
    stripTags from string1 --> "“Megan Fox”"
    stripTags from string2 --> "“iPhone 8”"
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    to stripTags from s as text
        local s
        
        # Eliminate linebreaks and join to form one line of text
        set the text item delimiters to {null, linefeed, return}
        set s to the text items of s as text
        
        # Use bash to isolate all the various tags within the string
        # Note: not suitable for tags with irregular content, such as
        # any that unexpectedly contain '<' or '>' as part of their
        # text content.  However, that shouldn''t be an issue here.
        do shell script "egrep -io -e '<[^>]+>' <<<" & the quoted form of s
        
        # Use the tags as a basis for elimination using AS's TIDs
        set the text item delimiters to {null} & paragraphs of the result
        set s to the text items of s as text
        
        return s
    end stripTags
```

`string1` is a copy of your variable `FirstTitle`, including the line breaks that it contained (I'm not sure whether these were in their intentionally or an artefact of when you copied your script over into the browser); their presence or absence doesn't affect the efficacy of my script, but merely necessitated the two lines at the start of the `stripTags` handler that gets rid of them.

`string2` is the text you supplied at the bottom of your question.

I've shown the output of each of these following processing.  I retained the double so-called "smart"-quotes that are part of the string and lie outwith the tags; I did see that you had opted to eliminate them, but their presence here—merely for demonstration purposes—are a nice visual reassurance that the script targets only the tags, and preserves the text in between.  I hope you don't mind if I leave those smart-quotes for you to deal with as you wish.

Let me know if you have any queries.

#### ADDED 2018-05-12:

@cjeccjec Thank you for updating the website information with the correct URL.  Tip for next time: include the code you're using to get the title.  It'll be easier for people to help you and it will attract more help as well.

Luckily, this problem seems quite straightforward.  Using `getElementsByClassName()` is a good idea, and you even managed to identify the classname of interest, `term-keyword__keyword`.  Well done.

The elements assigned to that classname are `<p>` elements.  They **do** have a `title` property, but it's empty, so I suspect that's not what you're using nor what you're after at all.

They also have a property called `textContent`, which, as it suggests, returns the text contained within the element, i.e. the labels of the items being compared in this game.  I believe **that's** what you're after, **and** it's completely free from `ReactJS` tags.

This code returns an array of the `textContent` properties from the three loaded `p.term-keyword__keyword` tags on the site at any one time: the two currently visible and in play being compared; and one off-screen to the right waiting to scroll into view for the next comparison.

```
    Array.from(document
              .getElementsByClassName('term-keyword__keyword'),
               e=>e.textContent.slice(1,-1)
              );
```

I also took the liberty of slicing off the quotes from the beginning and end of the texts.

Incorporate this into AppleScript like so:

```
    tell application "Safari" to set labels ¬
        to do JavaScript "Array.from(document" & ¬
        ".getElementsByClassName('term-keyword__keyword')," & ¬
        "e=>e.textContent.slice(1,-1));" in the front document
    
    --> {"Microsoft Word", "Moobs", "Malaysia"}
    
    item 2 of labels --> "Moobs"
```

Those were the results that I got returned whilst playing the game.  I was trying to guess whether "Microsoft Word" or "Moobs" had more internet searches, which I got correct; then "Malaysia" scrolled into view as I already knew it would.

Using this method, you don't need to strip any `ReactJS` tags away, nor any quote marks.

Comment: on the website "higherorlower.com" I am using javascript "document.getElementsByClassName" to return the title of the given search amount

Comment: @cjeccjec Sorry for my delay in replying—have been unwell.  The website `higherorlower.com` returns an `Error 403` (Forbidden).  Is it still working for you; do I require special authorisation to access it ?

Comment: where the class name is "term-keyword__keyword" (0) using the javascript I can still obtain a title. The game has to be started on classic. I've realised the actual website is http://www.higherlowergame.com/

Comment: @cjeccjec Yup, that website worked.  I've updated my answer with the solution to your problem.  As it turns out, you don't need to bother with stripping off unwanted HTML code at all.  Win!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easily solvable by using the **NSString** in the **Foundation** framework, which includes support for regular expressions.

```
use framework "Foundation"
set sample1 to "<!-- react-text: 477 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 478 -->iPhone 8<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 479 -->”<!-- /react-text -->"
log sample1
log removeHTML(sample1)

on removeHTML(instr)
    set nStr to current application's NSString's stringWithString:instr
    return (nStr's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"<[^>]+>" withString:"" 
        options:(current application's NSRegularExpressionSearch) 
        range:{0, nStr's |length|()}) as text
end removeHTML
```

Outputs:

```
<!-- react-text: 477 -->“<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 478 -->iPhone 8<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 479 -->”<!-- /react-text -->
”iPhone 8”
```

Comment: @CJK Of course it returns "iPhone 8" as it should. I made a copy/paste typo from the Script Editor log...